# Reverse Proxy for multiple Server

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

Hi I'm totally new to the topic of Hosting.

I own a dedicated rootserver on which I'm virtualizing diffrent hosts like webserver and gameserver for example.

My Problem is that I just have one external IP and want to use specific (sub)domains to access the differnt servers like:
gameserver1.example.com
cloud.example.com
ts3.example.com

Sometimes there will be multiple gameservers with the same game, for different users.

Is there any soltion which would suite my needs?

Comment: You are looking for a load balancing proxy. Apache webserver is one option. You may also need to use iptables for non http(s) protocols.